# How to fix a gconf error?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gconf

Whenever I log into Ubuntu(10.04), I get the following error.

**GConf Error:**

> Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details - 1: Could not send message to GConf daemon: Connection is closed)

My start menu and bottom panel have gone missing. How do I re-configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution and now it is working fine. All of my desktop apps were back and there were no error messages during reboot.

I issued the commands:

> **mv .gconfd/saved_state .gconfd/.saved_state**
>
> **pkill -x gnome-session**

(see [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1082257.html))

Answer (score 0):

see this forum thread and see if any of the fixes help:

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1169825.html